# Make/take a photograph?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, verbs, collocation

In English we say *"take a photograph"* whereas in some other languages one would say *"make a photograph"*.

The French say *"take"* even though they *"make"* far more often than we do in English, and Germans say *"make"*. The Spanish are also in the *"take"* camp, so it seems to be related to romance/germanic distinction, further afield, Russians say *"make"* (I think).

Some say that cameras steal your soul. Saying that a camera removes (one Spanish verb is literally *"remove"*) rather than constructs the photograph seems to betray a very different philosophy and attitude to photography as a creative process.

So, how did we end up using *"take"* rather than *"make"*?

Comment: ["Take a note, Miss Jones"](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-3465878-take-a-note-miss-jones.php)

Comment: Yup, that's similar.

Comment: The Spanish are in _both_ camps since you can use _tomar_, _sacar_, or _hacer una foto_.

Comment: @terdon I wasn't sure about hacer, I thought it was uncommon, and was not sure that it meant "make" rather than "carry out"/"do", so I didn't mention it.

Comment: That wasn't a correction @Lukas, I was just intrigued by your point and thought I'd mention that the case of Spanis is even stranger! On a side note, (modern) Greek is also in the _take_ camp.

Comment: Both "take a photograph" and "make a photograph" are used in English, though the former is far more common among the general public. A discussion of the distinction: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/does-a-photographer-take-pictures-or-make-pictures

Comment: @terdon My understanding of Spanish is basically non-existent, so I thought I should explain why I said what I said, in case I am woefully wrong.

Comment: @coneslayer Cool. It's interesting that they seem to be discussing it from a far more individual perspective than I was intending here.

Comment: 'Screen capture' is a similar expression. If there ever was an allusion to misappropriation, it's been bleached out here. And with 'take notes', there is little sense of anything sinister. I think that there is a parallel with 'seize the opportunity' which again has few negative connotations. Nowadays, _take_ in take a photo / walk / left / bath is delexical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The take doesn't have to imply misappropriation. Personally, I think of it hinting at there being a certain verity above things that are made. Even for delexical words, for some reason one word has been chosen above another at some point in time.

Comment: I'm wondering if the age of the instant photo had something to do with it, or when one had to literally make the photo, as now we (until the digital age) take the photo and get someone else to make it

Comment: The expression's older than instant photos. In Lewis Carroll's poem, "Hiawatha's Photographing," he wrote: "Next, his better half took courage; She would have her picture taken."

Comment: @gmcgath I'm inclined to agree, but for a long time many people developed their own photographs.

Answer (score 6):

Merriam-Webster Online gathers several related senses of [*take*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take):

> **11 b** (1) : to obtain as the result of a special procedure : ascertain <*take* the temperature> <*take* a census> (2) : to get in or as if in writing <*take* notes> <*take* an inventory> (3) : to get by drawing or painting or by photography <*take* a snapshot> (4) : to get by transference from one surface to another <*take* a proof> <*take* fingerprints>

The common meaning here is to record something by procedure or writing instrument.

I hadn't previously seen the uses *take a painting* or *take a drawing,* so I consulted Google books and found that *taking a drawing* was [common in the 1800s, during the rise of photography](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20a%20drawing%20of,take%20a%20drawing%20of,take%20a%20painting%20of,take%20a%20photograph%20of&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). This sense of *take* appears to have arisen in the late 1700s; note this example from *The New-York Magazine or, Literary Repository* (1792):

> Mr. Peale, we hear, is engaged to **take a painting of** this extraordinary person, to preserve to future time the features and form of a person furnished with nerves and constitution to exist to so surprising an age, on that ocean of time which has long ago swallowed up so many millions of his contemporaries.

While *making a drawing* was always more common than *taking* one, I suspect that the latter usage took hold for photographs because the process of capturing (taking) a photograph is distinct from printing (making) it, and the taking happens when you open the shutter.

Answer (score 3):

We definitely [**take**, rather than **make** photos](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took%20a%20photo,took%20a%20photograph,made%20a%20photo,made%20a%20photograph&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), but arguably it's not just a random idiomatic usage.

Semantically, you usually *take* something that already exists, whereas you *make* something new. Most of the time, most people don't see pressing a camera button as a particularly "creative" act. The image being recorded is already "out there"; you're just making/taking a copy of it.

Similar issues arise with *taking/making notes* (in a lecture, for example)...

> [listened and **took** notes](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22listened%20and%20made%20notes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22listened%20and%20took%20notes%22&oq=%22listened%20and%20took%20notes%22&gs_l=serp.3...2981.4560.0.5232.8.8.0.0.0.0.94.564.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab._rSp8qsB-TI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.d2k&fp=b9699f89cad4737a&biw=1258&bih=865) (8390 hits in Google Books)
>    [listened and **made** notes](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22listened%20and%20made%20notes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (2650 hits)

Note that with *note-taking* the bias isn't so strong. Personally, I think partly because *on average* note-taking is a more creative process. Perhaps I only think that because I'm trying to rationalise an established idiomatic usage that "makes sense" to me, but to the extent that I would ever speak of "making" a photo, it would be in some "artistically creative" context, not throwaway snapshots.

Comment: "Taking a shit" is definitely in your favor.

Comment: @Lucas: *Notes* can be made or taken; *shits* are nearly always taken, but if someone ***made** a shit* you'd probably understand it to mean the same thing. It all depends on the noun though - when you *take tea* and *make tea* you're doing *different* things.

Comment: @Lucas The general sense of _take_ meaning “to make, obtain” comes [from the late 14c.](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=take&searchmode=none). The refinement of that to mean “make a picture” is later, possibly 1790s based on my Google Books searches. Whether to use _take, make,_ or both seems idiomatic for each usage.

Answer (score 0):

While I am sure you can use both, generally you take things that exist and you make things that do not exist.  You can take a picture if the image exists (e.g. a photo) and you can make a picture if you are creating it from scratch (e.g. painting).  Another way to put it is that a photo is taking an image that is there, but painting is creating a likeness (or not in many cases).